# Checkbox js toggling incorrectly

Tags: javascript

I have a check box in my registration form like this:

```
<form name="reg" id="reg" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="return validate('tos')" name="tos"/>
</form>
```

And I am using JS to check if its ticked, and if so, display a green tick in the form. However, its not actually ticking the check box when its clicked but it is loading the green tick.

Additionally, clicking it a second time doesn't remove the green tick which it should, because the user effectively unticked the check box.

So my JS is this:

```
function validate (type){
    output = [];
    var x = document.getElementById("reg");

    if (type == 'tos'){
        div = 'result_tos';
        input = x.elements[4].checked;

        if (input){
            output.push('<img src="correct.png"/>');    
        } else {
            output.push('You must agree to our terms of service in order to join !');
        }

        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = (output.join('')); //display result
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole `validate` function? Is that function returning any values or calling `preventDefault`? Try taking out the `return` part from the `onclick` in the `input`.

Comment: It is calling the function because the green tick displays...(correct.png) part of the script.

Comment: @wnwall i removed the return but didn't change any thing :(

Comment: What is `x`? can you post the whole function?

Comment: @wnwall my mistake i forgot to put that in when i didn't copy all the text - it gets elementbyid ("formname")  (see edit of question)

Comment: Note that `x.elements[4]` will get the fifth control in the form, the sample above only has one control so it should be `x.elements[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jsfiddle is a slightly modified version of your code that seems to be working fine. I don't think your error is here. (I'm not familiar with `elements`; is that IE specific? I changed that to work on other browsers.)

http://jsfiddle.net/QnDAg/1/

Comment: I think elements is used when referring to elements in a specific form

Comment: Ah, learned something new. Well I don't see an error. The only way for me to help you from here is if you posted an example page which demonstrated it not working.

Comment: Well i madea JS Fiddle but the function is not defined so i couldn't make an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxr6V/1/

Comment: I modified your JS fiddle by making 2 changes. (1) I moved the script to the HTML so that the function would be defined. (2) I changed the index in `elements` to `[0]` since there are no more elements in this example before the `tos` element. It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxr6V/2/

Comment: @Dave - I think you're headed for trouble accessing an element by going to it's indexed position. You're better off referring to the element by an `id` or `document.formName.elName`. I prefer `id`, personally.

Comment: if i use id do i still need to reference the form it is contained in?

Comment: No, and I would suggest using `id` as well. Here's a modified version of your code that uses `id` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxr6V/12/

Comment: There is no need to reference the form or add an ID to the control. You can pass a reference to the element as `this` in the handler, i.e. `onclick="return validate(this)"`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how I would suggest you do this, which is more complex than the example given, but I'm struggling a little bit with the intended flow and the flow the OP is using:

**Mock HTML**

```
<form name="reg" id="reg" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree"/> Agreement<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ok" name="ok"/> Ok<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tos" name="tos"/> TOS<br/>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit Validation</button>
</form>
<h1>Display Output</h1>
<div id="display"></div>​
```

**Iterating Validation**

```
function validate (){
    var display = document.getElementById('display'),
        output = [],
        checks = ['agree','ok','tos'],
        check,
        msg;

    while (check = document.reg[checks.pop()]) {
        if (!check.checked) {
            switch (check.name) {
                case 'agree':
                    msg = 'You must AGREE!';
                break;
                case 'ok':
                    msg = 'You must OK!';
                break;
                case 'tos':
                    msg = 'You must TOS!';
                break;
            }

            output.push(msg);
        }
    }

    if (output.length == 0) {
        output = [
            'You have successfully validated!',
            '<img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>'
        ];
    }

    display.innerHTML = output.join('<br>'); 

    return false;
}
```

And don't forget the `window.onload` when you attach the event handler. Below isn't necessarily the preferred preferred method, but it's cleaner than inline handlers like `onclick="validate()"`.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.reg.onsubmit = validate;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bj5rj/2

Comment: Curious why you have onclick on the check box and a validate call in the js for onclick event in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Oops, I'm just noticing you were referencing something else. Give me a minute.

Comment: Wait, hold on, with `x`, is that meant to refer to your `input checkbox` element?

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("reg"); is the form...then its elements on x ..... so its the elements in the form its the 4th element in my form so its element [4]

Comment: There is no fourth element in your markup. Your code that's posted is confusing. Are you trying to determine if the TOS checkbox is checked before allowing someone to submit your form? Not to mention, that's a not so good way to do that.

Comment: But your example uses on submit rather than live.. =/

Comment: Live? Are you referring to `$.live()`, the jQuery event method?

Comment: No as in - it will do something without having to hit submit button.

Comment: That's what I thought you were doing. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bj5rj/5 I'm extrapolating a little bit here, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as below. Pass a reference to the element from the listener.

```
<form name="reg" id="reg" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="return validate(this)" name="tos">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validate(el) {
  // you don't really need a reference to the form, 
  // but here's how to get it from the element
  var form = el.form; 

  if (el.name == 'tos') {

    if (el.checked) {
      // show pass graphic (green tick?)

    } else {
      // hide checkbox and show text
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Swapping between displaying the tick and text should be done by setting a class value, that way you can change it to whatever you want in the markup and the script just toggles the two.

Comment: You don't have to pass `this`, it's already scoped in the callback to the element's context.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—Yes you do and no it's not for a function called from an in–line listener. It has nothing to do with scope, it's about how the function is called.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I stopped using inline handlers so long ago I forget how they work.